# asp chart x/y axis lines not changing color

Tags: .net, charts

I have an asp chart. I would like the main x/y axis lines to be white. However they keep showing up black. Can someone tell me what option either in html or the code behind will change the x/y axis lines?
[image]

Comment: [Axis.LineColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.linecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: could you add some more info to the question ?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/534335) I believe it gives an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ChartArea just use the line color property for both AxixX AND AxisY.

Example.

```
AxisX Interval="1" Title ="x1" LineColor ="#993366" 


 AxisY Interval="1" LineColor ="#9999ff" Title="x2"
```